# Bitbucket CI pipeline with multiple tools and dependencies

Tags: java, continuous-integration, bitbucket-pipelines

I am working on a product that have multiple services like mongodb, cassandra, kafka, redis, spark, storm, etc. I am using bitbucket pipeline for CI. Currently I am testing our application by mocking different services(tools/business). Now I want to write integration test and for that I need to setup bitbucket pipeline.

Should i use single image and install all of my tools on top of it or is there any way to use multiple images for a single build pipeline, if yes then how could i make a network of docker images on bitbucket CI environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a single image on the top level and overwrite it in a step. That’s all. Therefore, you’d have to use an image which contains everything you need.

Comment: This is not true any more.  BitBucket now allows up to four containers to run in a single pipeline.